# Site Master Error in Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i add ajax tool kit when i add site master page it shows me error like this  and also i add reference in web.config  how to add namespace of ajax control tool kit in asp.net

```
 ASP.NET runtime error: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help
    topic <location> for exceptions.
```

in this line

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication1.Site1" %>


any help?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try registering the Control like this

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" 
           Inherits="WebApplication1.Site1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
            namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

---

Also you want to make sure you do not have duplicated section in your `web.config` file.

Comment: i add but when i drug ajax control it show like this  <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
    </asp:ComboBox>  this is ajax comobox but it shows asp??

Comment: it should be like this `<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1"` did you add `ajaxtoolkit dll`?

Comment: yess.. i add dll ....but y i specially write ajaxtoolkiet:combox id="comobox1 .....when i drag ajax control it would be done this ..but it is not done when i drag control